# Telerik: Uncluster Bar Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radchart

I'm using Telerik Rad Chart to graph some data. I have a very simple data structure. One column of unique identifiers and another column of values to be graphed. For some reason the rad chart is creating a duplicate column of the same data. How do I prevent this?

```
<telerik:RadChart runat="server" ID="rcBar" DefaultType="Bar" DataSourceID="sdsBar" 
          SeriesOrientation="Horizontal" Width="475px" Height="500">          
             <PlotArea>
                <Appearance Dimensions-AutoSize="true" Dimensions-Width="450px" Dimensions-Height="475px"></Appearance>
                <XAxis Appearance-ValueFormat="General" DataLabelsColumn="Col1"></XAxis>
             </PlotArea>
             <Appearance Dimensions-Paddings="0"></Appearance>
           <ChartTitle Visible="false"></ChartTitle>
           <Legend Visible="false"></Legend>
         </telerik:RadChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating the RadChart from codebehind? I had the same issue building a time-measuring chart and when I created it programmatically it solved itself. Even adding background pictures and everything. This documentation helped me:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-building-programmatic-create.html